# Why do some of the geom_text labels flipped when added on a dodged geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, position-dodge

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), Group = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A"), sumGp = c(1L, 0L, 162L, 32L, 
9L, 2L, 0L, 0L), n = c(2L, 30L, 181L, 60L, 27L, 17L, 33L, 3L), 
    pct = c(0.5, 0, 0.895027624309392, 0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.117647058823529, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to visualize this with dodged `geom_col`, adding labels to it only when `sumGp` is not zero. My trick is to color the text white when `sumGp` == 0 (I understand this might not be the best way to label the numbers, but let's just do it this way to reproduce my main problem in this question).

Let's set up a `ggplot` function to make sure my problem is not related to accidentally changed codes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col <- function(df){
  ggplot(df |> mutate(label_pct = paste0(sumGp, "/", n)), 
         aes(as.character(ID), pct, fill = Group, label = label_pct)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(color = grepl("^0/", label_pct)), position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.5,
              show.legend = F) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("A" = "#4A765e", "B" = "orange3")) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("black", "white")) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent) +
    labs(x = "ID") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth = 1),
          plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold"),
          legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          legend.position = "top")
  }
```

Everything goes well with this code:

```r
plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col(df)
```

[image]

But when the values of "A" and "B" flipped, the behavior of `geom_text` becomes weird, where `position_dodge` does not seem to affect the text on the dodged bar if one of them contained zero:

```r
df2 <- df |> mutate(Group = case_match(Group, "A" ~ "B", "B" ~ "A"))

plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col(df2)
```

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening? Someone suggested to add `aes(group = Group)` to fix the problem, but that did not answer why ploting with `df` is fine without grouping. Also, that did not answer why only the pair with `sumGp` == 0 was affected without grouping (in `df2`).

Comment: FYI, `grepl("0/", .)` is fragile, if you end up with `10/n` then it will falsely trigger. I think it'd be safer to do `aes(color = (sumGp < 1))` or `aes(color = grepl("^0/", .))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the grouping and can be fixed by mapping on the `group=` aes. I haven't digged deeper into your code. But especially when several variables and aesthetics are involved I would recommend to map on aesthetics locally and/or to explicitly map on the `group=` aes so that bars and text or ... are dodged by  the same variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col <- function(df) {
  ggplot(
    df |> mutate(label_pct = paste0(sumGp, "/", n)),
    aes(as.character(ID), pct, fill = Group, label = label_pct, group = Group)
  ) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(color = grepl("0/", label_pct)),
      position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.5,
      show.legend = FALSE
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("A" = "#4A765e", "B" = "orange3")) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("black", "white")) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent) +
    labs(x = "ID") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth = 1),
      plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold"),
      legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
      axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
      legend.position = "top"
    )
}

df2 <- df |> mutate(Group = case_match(Group, "A" ~ "B", "B" ~ "A"))

plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col(df2)
```

[image]

**Why does this happen?**

The underlying issue is the grouping or more precisely how the `group` variable is set internally by `ggplot2`. As document in several places, e.g. [in the docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html) the `group` variable is set using `plyr::id()` (see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/a90e8ed4082100efaeee953b3974c3ba43318b52/R/grouping.R#L25)) based on all discrete variables mapped on aesthetics with the `label` aes (and the facetting) variables being the only exceptions. Additionally, it's important to note that the value set for the `group` variable also depends on the order of the aesthetics inside `aes()`.

Before I go on, to show clearly what's going on I slightly changed the setup of your example, i.e. I added `label_pct` and a `color` column to the original dataset outside of your plotting function.

```r
df <- df |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    label_pct = paste0(sumGp, "/", n),
    color = grepl("0/", label_pct)
  )

plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col2 <- function(df) {
  ggplot(
    df,
    aes(as.character(ID), pct,
      fill = Group, label = label_pct,
      # group = Group
    )
  ) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(color = color),
      position = position_dodge(0.9),
      vjust = -0.5,
      show.legend = FALSE
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("A" = "#4A765e", "B" = "orange3")) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("black", "red")) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent) +
    labs(x = "ID") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth = 1),
      plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold"),
      legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
      axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
      legend.position = "top"
    )
}

df2 <- df |> 
  mutate(Group = case_match(Group, "A" ~ "B", "B" ~ "A"))

p1 <- plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col2(df)
p2 <- plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col2(df2)
```

For the `geom_col` the `group` is set according to `ID` and `Group` aka the variables mapped on `x` and `fill`. For your example this also means that each observation gets assigned to its own group. In contrast, for the `geom_text` the `group` also accounts for the variable mapped on `color`. As a consequence, already for `df` does the `group`ing differ for the `geom_col` and the `geom_text`. This can be seen by calling `plyr::id()` and checked using e.g. `layer_data`:

```
plyr::id(df[c("ID", "Group")], drop = TRUE)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7
#> attr(,"n")
#> [1] 8

layer_data(p1, i = 1)[["group"]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7

plyr::id(df[c("color", "ID", "Group")], drop = TRUE)
#> [1] 1 6 2 3 4 5 8 7
#> attr(,"n")
#> [1] 8

layer_data(p1, i = 2)[["group"]]
#> [1] 1 6 2 3 4 5 8 7
```

This said, even for `df` are the labels assigned to the right columns only by coincidence.

Now, when looking at `df2` we see that for the `geom_col` the values assigned to the `group` simply get swapped when swapping `A` and `B`. Hence, the bars are swapped too.

```
plyr::id(df2[c("ID", "Group")], drop = TRUE)
#> [1] 2 1 4 3 6 5 7 8
#> attr(,"n")
#> [1] 8
```

However, this is not the case for the `geom_text` layer. Here, the values assigned to `group` are swapped for all rows except for the first two. As a result the grouping for the first two rows or labels is the same as in the case of `df` and the labels are no longer assigned or aligned  to the correct bars.

```
plyr::id(df2[c("color", "ID", "Group")], drop = TRUE)
#> [1] 1 6 3 2 5 4 7 8
#> attr(,"n")
#> [1] 8
```

Comment: Thank you stefan! Any idea on why `group` is not needed in the case of `df` but `df2`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no (convincing) answer. Already had a closer look but still do not understand why this happens. Will have a closer look later.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was a bit busy this week. I had another look at the issue and added some explanatory notes on why this happens.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to not try to force the color, instead just emptying the string when the `sumGp` is 0.

```r
plot_geom_text_with_dodge_geom_col <- function(df) {
  df |>
    mutate(label_pct = if_else(sumGp > 0, paste0(sumGp, "/", n), "")) |>     # CHANGE
    ggplot(aes(as.character(ID), pct, fill = Group, label = label_pct)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black") +
    geom_text(# aes(color = grepl("0/", label_pct)),
              position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.5,
              show.legend = F) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("A" = "#4A765e", "B" = "orange3")) +
    # scale_color_manual(name = "Identity", values = c("black", "white")) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent) +
    labs(x = "ID") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth = 1),
          plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold"),
          legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          legend.position = "top")
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for checking my codes r2evans! Do you have any idea why `geom_text` with `position_dodge` works on `df` but not `df2`? This is the major problem I wanted to understand in this question :( But I really really appreciated your help!!! +1 !

Comment: Not certain, but I agree with stefan that it's most likely a grouping issue. We can also fix it by adding `group=Group` to the text call, as in `geom_text(aes(color = grepl("^0/", label_pct), group = Group), ..)` in your original unchanged function.